# How to change z-index of amCharts axisGuides

Tags: amcharts

I am trying to visualize a filter in my stock chart by graying out data points which are affected by the filter. I'm using axisGuides on my valueAxis in order to achieve this. However, I also have axisGuides on my categoryAxis and unfortunately, these now disappear beneath my horizontal axisGuides.
Is there any way to change the z-index of those guides? Or does anybody have a different solution?

I have adapted an official amCharts example to show what I mean:
http://jsfiddle.net/wq97ujne/

I'm setting `plotAreaFillColors": '#ababab'` on my stock panel and `fillColor: "#ffffff"` on my valueAxisGuide.

I would like for the vertical guides to be drawn in front of and not behind the white area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set `above: true` for the categoryAxisGuides.